# How to enable a function to take pointers pointing to different classes?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct ClassA
{
    int m_age = 1;
    int m_height = 2;
};

struct ClassB
{
    int m_age = 3;
    int m_height = 4;
    char m_grade = 'C';
};

void print_classa_info(const ClassA* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "age: " << ptr->m_age << std::endl;
}

void print_classb_info(const ClassB* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "age: " << ptr->m_age << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ClassA classA;
    ClassB classB;

    print_classa_info(&classA);
    print_classb_info(&classB);
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**> As you can see, the `print_classX_info` only refers to the common fields of both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. Also assume we cannot modify both `ClassA` and `ClassB`. How can I define a function that can take a pointer pointing to either `ClassA*` or `ClassB*` so that I don't have to define two print functions for `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a function template.

```
template <typename T>
void print_class_info(const T* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "age: " << ptr->m_age << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to ensure `T` must be `ClassA` or `ClassB`, you can apply [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) (for which you'll get a no matching function error when calling with other types, [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lOj7pnWHJQ1Hsu9A)). e.g.

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, ClassA> || std::is_same_v<T, ClassB>>
print_class_info(const T* ptr)
{
    std::cout << "age: " << ptr->m_age << std::endl;
}
```

And since C++20 we can also use [Constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Constraints).

```
template <typename T>
void print_class_info(const T* ptr)
requires std::is_same_v<T, ClassA> || std::is_same_v<T, ClassB>
{
    std::cout << "age: " << ptr->m_age << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q14sw81Lx5rowvY6)

Comment: std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, ClassA> || std::is_same_v<T, ClassB>, void>

Comment: @q0987 The 2nd template parameter of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) has default argument `void`, so it's fine not to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what templates are for:

```
template<typename T>
void print_class_info(const T* ptr)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, ClassA> || std::is_same_v<T, ClassB>);

    if (ptr != nullptr)
        std::cout << "age: " << ptr->m_age << std::endl;
}
```

This guarantees that `T` must be either `ClassA`, or `ClassB`.

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/X8m94u).

As @Remy Lebeau points out in the comments, you might prefer to just use references instead of pointers. This avoids having to do `nullptr` checks, since the function must be called with an object instead.

```
template<typename T>
void print_class_info(const T &ref)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, ClassA> || std::is_same_v<T, ClassB>);

    std::cout << "age: " << ref.m_age << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the function now needs to be called like this

```
print_class_info(classA);
print_class_info(classA);
```

Comment: You don't need the `static_assert`. Remo e it so any class with an accessible `m_age` field can be passed in. The code will fail to compile if that requirement is not met. Also, you should consider passing the object parameter by reference instead of pointer to avoid nulls

Comment: @RemyLebeau added the nullptr check, thanks. I don't want to remove the static_assert, as I think the OP *wants* this constraint.

Comment: I would still suggest changing the pointer to a reference, no need to involve pointers at all: `template<typename T>
void print_class_info(const T& ref) { static_assert(...); std::cout << "age: " << ref.m_age << std::endl; }` ... `ClassA classA; ClassB classB; print_class_info(classA); print_class_info(classB);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a good idea. Added that to the answer, thanks.